# Смена кодировки при $get

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

День добрый!

Передаю через `$get` запрос на контроллер, в нем есть `QueryStringParameter` с кириллицей.

`Action` принимает мои параметры, но кириллицу не может правильно декодировать. Причем, это проблема только в IE11, в Mozilla все работает.

Чего только не пробовал, кодировал эти символы на стороне контроллера в 1251, UTF-8 и прочие.. Так и не получил нормальный русский текст. Пробовал еще через `Url.Decode`.

```
 public ActionResult AddNewCom(string idEvent, string Com, string RouteC, string Aut, string Actions)
```

Url:

```
/PCMS/AddNewCom?idEvent=b282c0fb-0092-4ef2-8f43-2e397d7551e0&Com=23&RouteC=%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd+%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd+%ef%bf%bd+%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd%ef%bf%bd&Aut=112&Actions=134"
```

Проблема с параметром `RouteC`. На стороне JavaScriptа ссылка на метод формируется корректно, с русскими символами. Но на стороне сервера не раскодируется назад.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

JS:

```
 var tex = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("AddNewCom", "PCMS", new { idEvent = "guid", Com="comm", RouteC="routecrit", Aut="authorname", Actions="acts" }))";
                var obj = $('#ddlCriteria').data("ejDropDownList");                
                tex = tex.replace("comm", $("#RTEComment").val());
                tex = tex.replace("routecrit", obj.option("text"));
                tex = tex.replace("authorname", $("#RTEAuthor").val());
                tex = tex.replace("acts", $("#RTEActions").val());
                tex = tex.replace("guid", selectedEventID);


                $.get(tex, function (rawData) {

                });
```

Comment: А можно код самого запроса посмотреть?

Comment: @RazGalstyan добавил JS

Comment: Кстати, вы слишком часто используете `Html.Raw`. Это небезопасно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov тогда почему эта некорректная ссылка отрабатывает в Firefox ?

Comment: @Exodium тьфу ты! Не заметил всех ваших replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед вставкой в URL строковых значений надо их url-кодировать. Браузер, конечно, может и сам попытаться это сделать... но не факт что у него получится то, что вы от него ожидаете.

Делается это функцией encodeURIComponent:

```
tex = tex.replace("routecrit", encodeURIComponent(obj.option("text")));
```

Но, вообще говоря, JQuery предоставляет и более простые способы формирования запросов. Например, можно сделать так:

```
$.get("/PCMS/AddNewCom", {
    idEvent: selectedEventID,
    Com: $("#RTEComment").val(),
    RouteC: obj.option("text"),
    Aut: $("#RTEAuthor").val(),
    Actions: $("#RTEActions").val(),
}, function (rawData) {
```

Comment: спасибо! проверю на днях.